# Enforce uniqueness in thinky (rethinkdb)

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb, thinky

In the thinky.io docs the following pattern is described to enforce uniqueness:

```
var Model = thinky.createModel("user",
    name: type.string()
}, {
    pk: "name"
});
```

Where the name property is assigned to the primary key.

Is this a typo? That is, should it read:

```
var Model = thinky.createModel("user", {
    name: type.string()
}, {
    pk: "name"
});
```

Also for anyone familiar with thinky who has used this pattern before, is there a similar way of assigning uniqueness as it is done in mongoose (mongodb):

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, unique: true }
});
```

Thanks.

Update: 
link to the docs
https://thinky.io/documentation/faq/

Comment: Yes, definitely a typo as the first example is not valid.

Comment: thanks quick 'sanity' check...I informed the faq owner so I am sure it will be fixed up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, definitely a typo as the first example is not valid.